# VisualC++ in memory Uncompression

Tags: winapi, mfc, visual-c++-2010

I have a "stringstream" variable that stores some compressed binary data in gzip format.

I want to decompress this stringstream variable in memory.

First of all, for in-memory decompression of binary data in gzip format, what third party library do you suggest to use ?

I noticed zlib library for compression/decompression of gzip and deflate formats.

However, the two functions handling decompression that zlip provides do not seem to meet my needs exactly:

```
int uncompress (Bytef *dest, uLongf *destLen, const Bytef *source, uLong sourceLen); 

int gzread (gzFile file, voidp buf, unsigned len);
```

The first one (uncompress) requires me to know the length of the decompressed data in advance to properly allocate enough memory for storage. In my case, it is unknown.

On the other hand, the second one (gzread) takes a file as input, not a memory buffer.

What do you suggest for an "efficient" in-memory decompression using zlip or some other library ?

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't gzipped data in binary format? Then `stringstream` is not a good choice to store the data unless you encode it so it can be stored as non-zero `char` values. The reason is that `stringstream` expects its data to be strings, and strings are terminated by a zero, which is valid binary data.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be some decompression filters for gzip in the Boost library, this might be worth looking into:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/gzip.html